# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql

He intentado mostrar los datos de una tabla de `Mysql` con `php`, pero me sale el error:

> "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
> mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line
> 12"

```
<?php

require ("conexion.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query); 

?>


<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<p>ID:</p> <?php $row["id"]; ?>
<p>Nombre:</p> <?php $row["nombre"]; ?>
<p>Precio:</p> <?php $row["precio"];?>

<?php };?>
```

Comment: Has duplicado la pregunta @Diego , revíselo y elimina una de las dos para evitar confusiones

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la siguiente linea

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
```

Por :

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
```